# Appropriate definitions for stage-separation and separation tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've adjusted tagging on a few questions so that [stage-separation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stage-separation) appears on questions about separation events involving

- stages
- capsules
- "pseudo-stages" like Apollo command and service modules

and [separation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separation) appears on questions about other kinds of separation events, including things like

- boosters
- fuel tanks
- fairings
- parachutes

But the appropriate space words needed to define these two in their wiki excerpt escape me.

What might clear, concise, accurate<sup>†</sup> and exclusive definitions for these two tags be?

---

<sup>†</sup> while the distance between two nearby spacecraft can be called the separation, the event itself is called a [conjunction](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunction).